# Il(d)asm roundtrip with xaml and other resources?

Tags: .net, xaml, resources, .net-assembly, il

I have a C# assembly foo.exe that I'm trying to dissasemble, modify and reassemble. The exe references a bunch of other assemblies, uses xaml for UI and has some managed and some unmanaged resources.

After my attempt at a decompilation roundtrip the application crashes during startup with an error like this:

*The component 'Fu' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Bar;component/baz.xaml'.*

What does that mean exactly and what might I have done wrong?

In my naive attempt to perform the roundtrip, this i what I did:

```
> ildasm.exe /out=foo.exe.il foo.exe
```

This produced an .il file, one .res file and some .resource files. I proceeded to modify the il. Next I tried assembling the exe again like this:

```
> ilasm.exe /output=foo.exe /resource=afile.res /exe foo.exe.il
```

Comment: **Update:** The modification I performed was removal of the public key (to remove strong name signing). After poking around in the resource files I noticed that the baml files contains references to the publickey. Trying to remove this reference I got stuck again. I would like to convert the .resource file to a .resx file, but `resgen fobo.resource fobo.resx` produces the error: _Message: "Item named 'resources/img.png' of type 'System.IO
.PinnedBufferMemoryStream' cannot be added to the resource file because it is not serializable."_ Ideas anyone?

Comment: Have you tried Mono Cecil? I believe it supports modifying existing assemblies, but I'm not sure how well does it work with resources.